# Split an excel file based on column values

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have an excel data file with 2 sheet named "Data" and "GL Data"

Both these sheets contain a column called "Leader" which has 4 different names - say D1, D2, D3 and D4

I have 4 other workbooks named - Data_D1, Data_D2, Data_D3 and Data_D4 each with 2 sheet named "Data" and "GL Data".

I need to put each Leader's data in their sheet. That is :

1- Apply a filter on Leader column in sheet "data" and select D1

2- copy the filtered rows to "data" sheet of workbook Data_D1

3- Apply a filter on Leader column in sheet "GL data" and select D1

4- copy the filtered rows to "GL data" sheet of workbook Data_D1

5- Repeat the above steps for D2, D3 and D4

I am wondering if there's a better way of doing this quickly. I searched online but couldn't find anything. Any help would be useful. Thank you.

EDIT: Wrote some VBA code (see answer below). Facing some problem with its working.

Comment: Hi Adnan! Can you share please some samples of your worbooks or sheets, at least some pictures.

Comment: Hi Mohamad, I wrote some VBA for this but there is some problem. Let me know if you can help. Posted the code in answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code but I can't seem to figure out why the second time the second loop runs, the filtered values are not copied. Do I need to reset the filter or something ? The first loop seems to be working.

```
Sub foo()
    Dim yr As String
    Dim lastPd As String
    Dim thisPd As String
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim vals As Variant
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim strNames(1 To 4) As String
    Dim fileNames(1 To 4) As String
    Dim path As String
    Dim sourceFileName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    yr = "2022"
    sourceFileName = "sourcefilename.xlsx"
    path = "path to the file"
    
    'populate the arrays
    strNames(1) = "D1"
    strNames(2) = "D2"
    strNames(3) = "D3"
    strNames(4) = "D4"
    
    fileNames(1) = "Data_D1.xlsx"
    fileNames(2) = "Data_D2.xlsx"
    fileNames(3) = "Data_D3.xlsx"
    fileNames(4) = "Data_D4.xlsx"
    
            
    For i = 1 To 4
     Set x = Workbooks.Open(path & sourceFileName)
     x.Activate
     Sheets("DATA").Activate
     lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     Set y = Workbooks.Open(path & fileNames(i))
     x.Sheets("DATA").Range("A1:N" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=strNames(i)
     x.Sheets("DATA").Range("A1:L" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
     y.Sheets("DATA").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
    Next i
    
            
    For j = 1 To 4
     Set x = Workbooks.Open(path & sourceFileName)
     x.Activate
     Sheets("GL Data").Activate
     lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     Set y = Workbooks.Open(path & fileNames(j))
     x.Sheets("GL Data").Range("A1:P" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=strNames(j)
     x.Sheets("GL Data").Range("A1:L" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
     y.Sheets("GL Data").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
    Next j
   
End Sub
```

Comment: This is really not how you should be using StackOverflow. You should edit your original post with the relevant info, and not post it as an answer. This is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I have some remarks about your VBA code :

1- The sourcefilename.xlsx file must be opened one. So, the opening
of the file has to be outside the two Next loop  (i and j).

2- The filter (Autofilter) must be disabled (turned to False) before each
change of criterion.

3- The copy/paste operation can be done in same
line, like this source.Copy destination

4- Try to add one row (first)
on DATA & GL Data sheets of sourcefilename.xlsx. Because, when you
filter the first line is considered as header, so it's not filtered.

5- In the header of the VBA module (the first line). you have to put
the syntax: *`Option Base 1`* so that the first element has the index
= 1 (and not 0).

I made some changes to your code. It does run perfectly :)

```
 Sub foo()
    Dim yr As String
    Dim lastPd As String
    Dim thisPd As String
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim vals As Variant
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim strNames(1 To 4) As String
    Dim fileNames(1 To 4) As String
    Dim path As String
    Dim sourceFileName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    yr = "2022"
    sourceFileName = "sourcefilename.xlsx"
    path = "path to the file"
    
    'populate the arrays
    strNames(1) = "D1"
    strNames(2) = "D2"
    strNames(3) = "D3"
    strNames(4) = "D4"
    
    fileNames(1) = "Data_D1.xlsx"
    fileNames(2) = "Data_D2.xlsx"
    fileNames(3) = "Data_D3.xlsx"
    fileNames(4) = "Data_D4.xlsx"
    
    'Open the Main workbook
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & sourceFileName 
    Set x = ActiveWorkbook
    For i = 1 To 4
        x.Sheets("DATA").Activate
        x.Sheets("DATA").AutoFilterMode = False
        lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Y = Workbooks.Open(Path & fileNames(i))
        x.Sheets("DATA").Range("A1:N" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=strNames(i)
        x.Sheets("DATA").Range("A2:L" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Y.Sheets("DATA").Cells(1, 1)
        Range("A1").Select
    Next i
    x.Sheets("DATA").AutoFilterMode = False
            
    For j = 1 To 4
     x.Activate
     x.Sheets("GL Data").Activate
     x.Sheets("GL Data").AutoFilterMode = False
     lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     Set Y = Workbooks(fileNames(j))
     x.Sheets("GL Data").Range("A1:P" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=strNames(j)
     x.Sheets("GL Data").Range("A2:L" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Y.Sheets("GL Data").Cells(1, 1)
     Range("A1").Select
    Next j
    x.Sheets("GL Data").AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```